# If it's not a function pointer, what is it?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Firstly, I find that `priority_queue<int>` will give higher priority to bigger integer.
While if we use `priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater>` then it do it in an inverse. Why?

Also, it seems that the comparator we put in the priority queue is not a function pointer. Instead it was defined as:

```
struct cmp{
    bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int&rhs) const
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I heard this is a very useful property of C++; could anyone explains this type of code to me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Functors - and their uses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses)

Answer (score 2):

It's a *functor*. It's basically a class/object that acts like a function by overloading `operator()`. For example in your code you could do:

```
cmp func;
func(1, 2);
// ^ calls operator()
```

You can read more about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses).

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of this kind of code is that if the type is templated you can put in a function pointer OR a class like the above (a functor). In either case they both work, the first is simpler while the second can have data given to it. Lambdas in c++11 makes them a little redundant though.

Answer (score 0):

Functors are often used to maintain *state* across an algorithm. Consider the following search function:

```
struct Foo { int x };
std::vector<Foo> fooList; // Imagine this is populated.

struct FindFunc
{
    FindFunc(int toFind) : val(toFind) {}
    bool operator()(const Foo& el) { return el.x == val; }
    int val;
};

// Seach the list of Foo objects for one where member x is 42
std::find_if(fooList.begin(), fooList.end(), FindFunc(42));
```